# Does Cloudwatch FilterLogEvents return log events in chronological order?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We're trying to debug an issue with inconsistent logs retrieved from Cloudwatch logs. The issue is that a few logs in a random time range will be missing in the chronological order, and will be present after scrolling a bit further down. We retrieved the logs using filterLogEvents function.
I want to know if the log events returned by cloudwatch filterLogEvents are always obtained in chronological order

Comment: update: the inconsistency issue seems to be sporadic. cloudwatch claims to sort the logs based on timestamp, but sometimes there's an inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

cloudwatch claims to sort the logs based on timestamp:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).